# spring resttemplate exchange returns null second time used

Tags: java, spring, rest, testng, resttemplate

I have a bunch of testng tests. When I run the tests individually they pass, when I run them in a suite the first test passes but the rest fail because the response from the exchange is null.

I have no idea why this happening can anybody suggest what could cause this?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Dependent test cases - test1 could modify something. So test conditions for following tests are changed. Some code would be helpful.